# Python socket - how can i connect to a different pc

Tags: python, sockets

How can i connect to a different pc using socket module in python? My code currently gives me 2 errors. The first error is:

```
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

line 7, in <module>
    s.connect((target, 80))**
```

Here is my code:

```
import socket

target = '192.168.1.0' #i convered the full ip

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

s.connect((target, 80))
s.send('HEAD / HTTP/1.1\nHost: ' + target + '\n\n')

print (s.recv(1024))
s.close()
```

Comment: Do you have a server on the remote pc listening for connections on port 80?

Comment: I havent checked

Comment: Which port is for Youtube?

Comment: @Johnny Mopp I have fixed the port number and it still gives me the same 2 errors

Comment: You need to clarify what you are trying to do. Are you trying to connect to a server on your local network? What does Youtube have to do with it? Are you trying to download a page from there? Maybe you want [scrapy](https://scrapy.org/) or something similar.

Comment: I am tryind to open a connection with a computer

Comment: The error means that the computer you're trying to connect to isn't running a webserver.